# Is this internal DSL syntax possible in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dsl

I'm trying to create an internal DSL for Ruby, I haven't started coding it yet, and I'm wondering if this syntax is possible in Ruby:

```
IF more_than: 1, :class smells to: "god class", sense: HIGH and has "no temp attributes", sense: 0.5
THEN problem "some problem"
WITH ponderation percent: 10
```

And also:

```
IF more_than: 1, :class
{
    smells to: 'god class', sense: 2
    and
    (
        has 'no temp attributes', sense: 0.5 or
        smells to: 'extensive coupling', sense: 1.5 or
        has 'refused parent Bequest', sense: HIGH or
        smells to: 'tradition breaker', sense: LOW
    )
    and
    (
        has :Method
        {
            smells to: 'extensive coupling', sense: 1.5
        }
    )
}
THEN
{ 
    problem "abusive conceptualization"
}
WITH
{
    ponderation percent: 10
}
```

**UPDATE:**
:D I'm still defining the DSL's requirements, such is my starting point, I'm considering either a custom parser or Ruby. What would you say is a better idea, to create a custom parser for it or use Ruby?

Comment: It might be possible, yes. So you should start coding it.

Comment: :P Just want to be sure the syntax isn't invalid Ruby.

Comment: Well, I hope you will be able to bend syntax requirements if issues arise :)

Comment: Haha, yeah I can. Nice looking blog, btw.

Comment: ruby -c will check syntax for you

Comment: checking it out... Seems to fail on some accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The problem is with these constructs:

```
:class to
```

You cannot pass arguments to a symbol, only to methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative version that is valid ruby syntax:

```
IF CLASS Student {
    smells to: 'god class', sense: 2 and
    has 'no temp attributes', sense: 0.5 or
    smells to: 'extensive coupling', sense: 1.5 or
    has 'refused parent bequest', sense: HIGH or
    smells to: 'tradition breaker', sense: LOW and
    has_method {
        smells to: 'extensive coupling', sense: 1.5
    }
}
THEN {
    problem 'abusive conceptualization'
}
WITH {
    ponderation percent: 10
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've been checking out possibilities, it is possible to use IF, THEN, WITH in uppercase.

Comment: Didn't put it as accepted answer, in case someone has an alternative that's more readable or closer to the original proposed DSL.